# Tabbed Dialog Pane using jquery UI and CSS

Tags: jquery

I have created a tabbed dialog pane just as seen here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/PGRhc/)
And this is my full source code:

```js
$.fn.tabbedDialog = function() {
  this.tabs();
  this.dialog({
    'modal': true,
    'minWidth': 400,
    'minHeight': 300,
    'draggable': true
  });
  this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').append($('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'));
  this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'right': '0',
    'top': '23px'
  });
  this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close > a').css({
    'float': 'none',
    'padding': '0'
  });
  var tabul = this.find('ul:first');
  this.parent().addClass('ui-tabs').prepend(tabul).draggable('option', 'handle', tabul);
  this.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
  tabul.addClass('ui-dialog-titlebar');
}
$('#tenant').tabbedDialog();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tenant">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tenant_details">My Tenant</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tenant_events">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tenant_jobs">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-tab-dialog-close"></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div id="tenant_details">
      some details
    </div>
    <div id="tenant_events">
      some events
    </div>
    <div id="tenant_jobs">
      some jobs
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I preview my code on the browser it just displays the content without formatting the tabbed panes. I have actually looked at my code and everything seems fine. Is there a better approach that I have not figured out?

Answer (score 0):

You did not link JQuery UI script and styles:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

In provided jsfiddle exactly that resources linked outside of the editor (on the left pane).

You'd **better** use last version of JQuery UI:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

**UPD**

Update your `<head>` (not in jsfiddle) with the following code:

```
<head>
    <title>Welcome to tabbed layout</title>
    <!-- 1. JQuery 2.1.1 JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. JQuery UI 1.11.3 JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 3. JQuery UI 1.11.3 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
```

**UPD2**

After updating JQuery UI to last version your close button has got broken. It happen because JQuery UI classes have been changed through the major versions.

Replace your button with that:

`<li class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></li>`

Replace all the close button classes with new class:

```
this.find('.ui-icon-closethick').append($('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'));
this.find('.ui-icon-closethick').css({'position':'absolute','right':'0', 'top':'6px'});
this.find('.ui-icon-closethick > a').css({'float':'none','padding':'0'});
```

And fix top shift by `top: 6px;`.

```js
$.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {
    this.tabs();
    this.dialog({'modal':true,'minWidth':400, 'minHeight':300,'draggable':true, 'autoOpen': false});
    var $dialog = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog');
    this.find('.ui-icon-closethick').append($('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')).css('position', 'static');
    $dialog.find('.ui-draggable-handle').append($('.ui-tabs-nav').removeClass().addClass('ui-tabs-nav')).addClass('ui-tabs');
    $dialog.find('.ui-dialog-title').remove();
}
$('#tenant').tabbedDialog();

$('button#show').click(function() {
  if ($('#tenant').dialog("isOpen")) {
    $('#tenant').dialog('close');
  }
  else
  {
    $('#tenant').dialog('open');
  }
});
```

```css
#tenant
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tenant">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tenant_details">My Tenant</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tenant_events">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tenant_jobs">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-icon-closethick"></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div id="tenant_details">
      some details
    </div>
    <div id="tenant_events">
      some events
    </div>
    <div id="tenant_jobs">
      some jobs
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="show">Show / hide</button>
```

**UPD3**

Open / close button added.

Comment: Serykh, Output remains on adding the ui and scripts as suggested

Comment: When I view page source it says jquery is not defined and this line of code throws an error: $.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {....... Regards

Comment: I've updated my answer. What "Output" do you mean? I only talking about your code from question, not JSFiddle code.

Comment: Sure! was missing the google api script! But it is kind of overfloating the close handle as seen on jsfiddle. Clicking on the close handle closes the pane

Comment: Thanks Serykh: but the close handle on the top right is missing. Regards

Comment: @PatrickNdu It got broken after changing the version of JQuery UI. In last version there are different classes for styling close button and other stuff. Give me more time to find proper classes.

Comment: Okay! Lets see how it rolls. Probably it would nice if you can modify the tab to pop up on button click. Regards.

Comment: Updated. Button appeared. But I realized it is not working yet. Dealing with it...

Comment: Hello friend! Are you with me?

Comment: @PatrickNdu Updated the snippet in answer.
I just rewrote your code from the beginning and get from another side: moved tabs to draggable dialog title. So, dialog is draggable, tabbed and closable now.

Comment: Thanks once again! But instead of refreshing my browser always to pop the dialog can I toggle the tab on  a button click? Thinking of user experience.

Comment: Hi Serykh: Are we together!

Comment: @Serykh  Question Answered! Thanks for the uplift.